# Range search: Identify points in intersecting circles

Tags: algorithm, datastructure

[image]

I am trying to identify points in two intersecting circles. The points are only in the first circle $O_1$. In many cases, the node density in the circle is not uniformly distributed. The radial node density grows exponentially with the distance from the origin $O_1$. Checking which points lie in the intersecting area one by one takes linear time. It takes a lot of time when the number of points is huge. Is there any kind of geometric data structure or method that I can use to improve this?

(The coordinates of points and $O_1, O_2, R_1, R_2$ are given.)

Comment: GDAL geometry overlay https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Geometry-class.html#Intersection to find the common area then intersects https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Geometry-class.html#Intersects on each point to check; the first step of intersect is extent intersects which returns a quick False if the extent of the query object is outside the intersected geometry extent. No need to reinvent the wheel here unless there is a specific reason why you can't use GDAL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not familiar with geographic information systems and geometric data structures. I know how to check if a point is in the common area. However, if I check the points one by one, it takes linear time. When the number of points is large, such as millions, tens of millions, it takes a long time. I hope to use geometric data structures such as STRtree, Rtree to achieve a lower complexity than linear. I hope to know not only about library functions but also the most appropriate data structure to solve a problem like this.

Comment: Have a look at the source code for PostGIS to view the primitives. PostGIS uses an R-Tree index https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html to speed up queries. The intersects operator can be multi threaded as OGR geometries are thread safe https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQMiscellaneous#IstheGDALlibrarythread-safe but it would be safer to clone the intersected geometry for each thread. Which programming languages do you have capability in? If you're trying to do this mathematically in python it will be slow, for speed you should be using C++ or ANSI C.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility to reduce the time of calculation is to reduce the number of points to test.

The intersection has some maximal and minimal values on the axis of the two dimensional space. Look for this values, they represent a rectangle, surrounding the intersection. Delete all points which are not inside this rectangle. This deletion is much less time consuming, than to look for points located inside the intersection of two circles. Afterwards start with the intersects algorithm of gdal as mentioned in the comments.

The calculation is still linear, but with a lower number of points to test.

Further improvement can be achieved as the points are only inside the first circle. So look at the image a posted in this answer. The dashed area is limited by the projection line of the points of intersection of both circle lines. on the other side by the circle 1 itsself. Therefore points left of the line are inside the intersection anyway. To use this information without projecting the point onto the connecting line, you can use the value closest to the center of circle 2, highlighted as vertical line.
[image]

I am not quite sure if a projection onto the connecting line between the centers can improve the result. The question here is, if the projection is more time consuming than checking the points for intersection. Looking at my drawn example I assume the projection could help, because the amount of deleted points as remarkable in a large variety of cases.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, you could also try creating a grid (100 x 100 perhaps) and classify the boxes as 'in', 'out' and 'suspect' (1+ vertex in, 1+ out) that way points indexed to their logical box row and column by C = (int) (X - X_Offset) / grid_width and R = (int) (Y - Y_Offset) / grid_height where offset is the lower left X,Y, then discarded if the box is 'out', retained with no further testing if the box is 'in' and only proximity tested if the grid box is 'suspect', that would hyper speed the points sorting and minimize the number of resource intensive intersects() operations.